# localStorage.removeItem based on value

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, local-storage

I am trying to add an account removal to my application. I store the accounts using one key with multiple values based on an API.

This is how I add the account:

```
addAccount(state,account){
    state.accounts[account.apikey] = account;
    localStorage.setItem(
        "accounts",
        JSON.stringify(state.accounts)
    );  
},
```

This is how my `localStorage` looks like:

```
key: accounts
{  
   "API Key 1":{ a bunch of info },
   "Api Key 2":{ a bunch of info }
}
```

My attempts trying to remove an account based on the API Key:

```
removeAccount(state,account){
    localStorage.removeItem(account.apikey);
    localStorage.removeItem(JSON.stringify(state.accounts));
    localStorage.removeItem(state);
    localStorage.removeItem(account);
    localStorage.removeItem(state.accounts[account.apikey]);
}
```

Neither of these ways actually delete the value. Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: You need to get `accounts` out of `localStorage`, `JSON.parse()` it, remove the account, `JSON.stringify()` the updated accounts Object again, and set `accounts` again.  `localStorage` is shallow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `localStorage.removeItem()` to remove entire `localStorage` entries. What you're trying to do is remove *part* of a `localStorage` entry. The only way to do this is to retrieve the object, remove the key like you would a normal JS object, and then re-set the `localStorage` entry:

```
removeAccount(state, account){
  const accounts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('accounts'));
  delete accounts[account.apikey];
  localStorage.setItem("accounts", JSON.stringify(accounts));
}
```

Comment: Exactly that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Data in localStorage is kept as a string. So you need to read the entire string, remove the item, then write it back:

```
let oldLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage['accounts']);
// Do something to oldLocalStorage, which is the JS object

// Write back to local storage
localStorage.setItem(
        "accounts",
        JSON.stringify(oldLocalStorage)
);
```